# Find the first difference between two buffers

Tags: buffers, ediff, diff

Given two buffers, how do I find the first character position where their contents differ? E.g. for contents `abcdef` and `abcDeF`, the first difference would be at point=4. For `abc` and `ab`, it would be at point=3.

Is there anything more direct than writing my own binary search based on `compare-buffer-substrings` to compare progressively smaller substrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why a binary search?  `compare-buffer-substrings` returns the number of chars that were equal.  So you can just do:

```
(goto-char (+ (point-min) -1
              (abs (compare-buffer-substrings
                    BUF1 nil nil BUF2 nil nil))))
```

you may want to let-bind `case-fold-search` around the call to specify if you prefer to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive, of course.

Comment: lol, sure enough the function's documentation says "if first string is less *after N-1 chars*". Somehow I managed to miss the *after N-1 chars* part and got the impression that the return value worked like `strcmp` in C. Should I just delete my question?